Unmuting a video upon 'enter section' with id="videos" and vice versa mute upon 'leave section'... Event Listener?
I am desperatly trying to find somewhere where I can control the audio of a  (unmute/mute) upon 'entering a specific section'  and vice versa, mute upon 'leave section'... Is this controlled by an JS Event Listener, or can it be controlled by some other manner?
Any help & code would be VERY much appreciated.
Thanks
Not managed to get anything to work, apologies

Could you explain more what is meant by 'entering a specific section' - do you mean as that section enters the viewport or when the mouse enters it or....?

You have to do it with JS if you want to switch mute/unmute.
Depending on what you mean with "entering a specific section" (you can enter a section by scrolling it into viewport or by hovering your mouse over it), you have to add the correct event listener.
The code might look like this:
//your section (replace 'section-1' by the ID your section has)
const section1 = document.getElementById('section-1');

//your video (replace 'video-1' by the ID your video has)
const video1 = document.getElementById('video-1');

//if you want to check the scroll position
document.addEventListener('scroll', checkScrollPositionToToggleMuteVideo1, false);

//if you want to check the section for mouse hover
section1.addEventListener('mouseover', unmuteVideo1, false);
section1.addEventListener('mouseleave', muteVideo1, false);

function checkScrollPositionToToggleMuteVideo1(e) {
    //if you choose to check the scroll position, you have to do some calculations here
    //...
    
    if(...) {
        unmuteVideo1();
    }
    
    else {
        unmuteVideo1();
    }
}

function unmuteVideo1() {
    video1.muted = false;
}

function muteVideo1() {
    video1.muted = true;
}

